# How does java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask work?

Tags: java, concurrency

could anyone tell me the logic behind `java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask`? I couldn't find the source code either on a very cursory look, so maybe someone can point me to it as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at a [hyperlinked source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.java#RecursiveTask).

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the java sources that are delivered with the JDK (src.zip) or decompile that.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a cross-reference for Java sources like `lxr` for Linux?

Comment: Yes, look at SLaks' answer, which you should be able to find when giving google this query: `java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask source` (several results on the first page). :)